# React Webpack - index.js.map module parse error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, loader, source-maps

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/my-project/dist/index.js.map 1:10

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> {"version":3,"file":"index.js","sources": .......

How can I fix this issue if I'm using custom webpack 5.